# How to aggregate one to many from array of ObjectId with Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using native mongodb driver on nodejs and I wish to be able to run a single query and retrieve all documents from another collection.

I have a `tags` collection: `id_`, `tag` and on my article collection I have `tags`that is an array of ObjectId

[image: Array of ObjectId]

now, when I retrieve the correct document I wish to have `tags`holding the `tag` value on the `tags`collection.

I can't wrap my head around that, I've been 
trying this but it only retrieves the first tag:

```
  db.orders.aggregate([
     {
        $unwind: "$tags"
     },
     {
        $lookup:
           {
              from: "tags",
              localField: "tags",
              foreignField: "_id",
              as: "tags_found"
          }
     },
     {
        $match: { "tags_found": { $ne: [] } }
     }
  ])
```

Is there a way to retrieve all the tags at once? If not, what is the best way to do so without using Mongoose but the native driver?

Comment: What's your MongoDB Server version?

Comment: it's 3.2.11 currently

Comment: yes, you're right, I managed to obtain the desired result looking at that answer

Comment: you can use `populate` query to retrieve multiple document.

Comment: it seems to me that it's not available on mongodb native driver, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at another question here on SO I almost managed to obtain what I wanted, thanks @chridam

Unfortunately it doesn't find articles without tags. is there a way to do that?

```
db.getCollection('articles').aggregate([
     {
        $unwind: "$tags"
     },
     {
        $lookup:
           {
              from: "tags",
              localField: "tags",
              foreignField: "_id",
              as: "tags_found"
          }
     },
      {
        $unwind: "$tags_found"
     },
     { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "tags": { "$push": "$tags" },
        "tags_found": { "$push": "$tags_found" }
    }},
     {
        $match: { "tags_found": { $ne: [] } }
     }
  ])
```